# Smack 4.2: Add admins to a MUC room

Tags: java, android, xmpp, ejabberd, smack

I´ve a problem to set admins, moderators etc... to a MUC room, which I want to create.

Here is the following code:

```
            // Create the nickname.
        Resourcepart nickname = Resourcepart.from("test");

        // Create the room
        chatRoom.create(nickname);

        // Set MUC config
        Form form = chatRoom.getConfigurationForm().createAnswerForm();
        form.setAnswer("muc#roomconfig_publicroom", true);
        form.setAnswer("muc#roomconfig_roomname", mGroupName);
        form.setAnswer("muc#roomconfig_persistentroom", true);
        form.setAnswer("muc#roomconfig_moderatedroom", true);

        FormField roomAdmins = new FormField();
        roomAdmins.setLabel("muc#roomconfig_roomadmins");
        roomAdmins.addValue("test@localhost");
        form.addField(roomAdmins);

        FormField accessMembers = new FormField();
        accessMembers.setLabel("muc#roomconfig_getmemberlist");
        accessMembers.addValue("participant");
        form.addField(accessMembers);


        chatRoom.sendConfigurationForm(form);
```

The room gets created without any errors.

If I want to fetch the admins with "multiUserChat.getAdmins().size();", I get always 0.

The room owner is always set. Thats working. But I can´t grant admin access to an existing owner or another user, who joined the room.

This is the log:

```
09-06 12:05:05.055 2531-3165/********* D/SMACK: SENT (0): <iq to='hdzy4zzdp31504692259578@conference.localhost' id='e8Ook-30' type='set'><query xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/muc#admin'><item affiliation='admin' jid='hdzy4zzdp3qcvv55u@localhost'></item></query></iq><r xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3'/>

09-06 12:05:05.145 2531-3166/********** D/SMACK: RECV (0): <iq from='hdzy4zzdp31504692259578@conference.localhost' to='HdzY4Zzdp3QCVv55U@localhost/test' id='e8Ook-30' type='error'><query xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/muc#admin'><item affiliation='admin' jid='hdzy4zzdp3qcvv55u@localhost'/></query><error code='405' type='cancel'><not-allowed xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas'/><text xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas'>Changing role/affiliation is not allowed</text></error></iq>
```

The XMPP software is an ejabberd (16.09) server.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try granting admin rights afterwards using, `muc.grantAdmin(user_jid);`

Comment: have you found any solution on this?

Comment: Yes, I was wrong with the "Admin". The admin means the "Server Admin", so I´ve found out that the "Owner" has the full rights to the room.

Comment: @Ghostw4lk Are you able to update "muc#roomconfig_getmemberlist"  values? because I'm trying to update but It alwasy show three values 'moderator, participants, visitor'

Comment: @user2934930 Please show here how the configuration works: https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0045.html, I´m not using MUC anymore. For mobile applications (in my case) there is a MUC Light protocol.